# How to receive realtime updates from Facebook in PHP?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I am trying to receive realtime updates from Facebook using their Realtime Updates API. I am just trying to get updates of the user's feed. I am using PHP to do all of this. I have it setup and verified, but I cannot access the response when they send it to my callback url. Is there a way to retrieve the json that is being sent to my callback url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> The request will have content type of application/json and the body will comprise a JSON-encoded string containing one or more changes.

This means you can not access it in PHP using the “normal” way of accessing values in $_POST, because this request is not of the format *form/urlencoded* – it does not contain *name=value* pairs, but instead *is* in itself just a JSON-encoded string.

You should be able to read this data using the [php://input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) stream wrapper – for example by simply using a line like

```
$inputdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

– and then you just use `json_decode` on the contents of this variable.

Comment: I have one more question if you do not mind, how do I parse the json received from facebook realtime updates? I am currently using this code, and it is outputting nothing. Any thoughts???                     if (isset($_POST)) {
 
 $inputdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($inputdata);
 echo $obj["entry"][0]["uid"];

}

Comment: As I said, $_POST will not be populated …